# Git proxy bypass

Tags: git, http, proxy

Git works in a proxied environment by setting the http.proxy configuration parameter.

For certain addresses I need to bypass the proxy. Is there a no-proxy/bypass-proxy configuration parameter?

Comment: An alternative is to use the SSH URL (instead of the HTTPS URL) to access Git repositories inside your company firewall. Any interaction with the repo using SSH will not attempt to go through the proxy.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The proxy can be overridden on a per-remote basis - see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config 
(look for the "http.proxy" and "remote.<name>.proxy" settings). Assuming you have the remote called "origin" then the command you could use to bypass proxy for this remote is:

```
git config --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

Comment: This edits the .git/config file in your working copy, which means that you would first need to clone the repository with the proxy unset. After cloning, you can reset the proxy, run the command as Jan posted, and then be able to pull and push without ever having to worry about it again.

Comment: I does not work, it still does connect to the proxy but without credentials.

Comment: seems to work fine for fetch, but not at all for "push", whereas the other answer with no_proxy=.my.domain works fine for push.

Comment: I'm getting "git : error: wrong number of arguments, should be 2"

Comment: @NikoBellic is correct, to clone with proxy unset the `-c` switch comes in handy; `git -c remote.origin.proxy= clone <repo> ` run the original answer once inside the folder to make this a repo specific permeant config.

Comment: @sandy Got it too on Windows, because if think the terminal merely ignores `""`. I directly edited `.git/config` to work around this. To be sure not to break anything, you can run `git config --add remote.origin.proxy " "`, then open `.git/config` and replace the line `proxy = " "` with `proxy = ""`

Comment: @sandy try removing the --add flag: `git config remote.origin.proxy ""`

Answer (score 44):

To bypass proxy for certain, usually a local address, all you need to do is:

```
export no_proxy=URLToIgnore
```

Where `URLToIgnore` is the URL that you want `Git` to ignore. 
 You can also ignore URLs ending with a certain word.

```
export no_proxy=.mylocal
```

Where all urls ending with `.mylocal` will get ignored. To ignore multiple URLs:

```
export no_proxy=.mylocal URLToIgnore
```

To make it permanent, add it to your `~/username/.bash_profile` file. If you cannot find `.bash_profile` file in your user root directory, then manually create it.

For more details:
[How to temporarily disable git http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523903/how-to-temporarily-disable-git-http-proxy)

Comment: This is useful but does not mention the fact it's only valid for linux (and perhaps mac as well) but not for Windows. Would user's environment variables work the same way for git as .bash_profile?

Comment: This did not work for git on my iMac. The accepted answer worked for git on my iMac.

Comment: You can do same in Windows.  Add an environment variable 'no_proxy' with value of URLS_to_Ignore.  Don't forget to start a new CMD shell.  Or to get working in current CMD just `set no_proxy=URLS_to_Ignore`.  Macs should work just same as *nix.  Don't forget to start a new shell terminal (or `source ~/.bash_profile` if the changes added to that).

Answer (score 11):

**For Windows users**

Accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612442/3717116) requires the git repo to exist before hand to work and the second best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646489/3717116) works only for linux & Mac. So in windows to make it work for *https://git-url.com/project/repo-name.git* try the following in a command prompt

```
set no_proxy=git-url.com
```

then

```
git clone git-url.com/repo-name.git
```

Now you will have a repo to apply the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have a Git 2.1.2+ if you want to set a config to an empty value, like

```
git config --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

Because if you decide to restore a proxy for that remote (here '`origin`')... **it will segfault with a Git older than 2.1.2 (Sept. 30th, 2014)**

See [commit c846664](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8466645edd1413c7efed824f5bddac457eb77f9) ([`tanayabh`](https://github.com/tanayabh))

### `make config --add` behave correctly for empty and `NULL` values

> Currently if we have a config file like,

```
[foo]
        baz
        bar =
```

> and we try something like, "`git config --add foo.baz roll`", Git will segfault.  Moreover, for "`git config --add foo.bar roll`", it will overwrite the original value instead of appending after the existing empty value.
>
> The problem lies with the regexp used for simulating `--add` in `git_config_set_multivar_in_file()`, "`^$`", which in ideal case should not match with any string but is true for empty strings.
>   Instead use a regexp like "`a^`" which can not be true for any string, empty or not.
>
> For removing the segfault add a check for `NULL` values in `matches()` in [`config.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c8466645edd1413c7efed824f5bddac457eb77f9/config.c).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are starting by cloning, the origin-config things are not so useful. When I find myself in that position I do.

```
$> no_proxy=$no_proxy,<git-url|ip> git clone ...
```

Note that this will be per command. To make this permanent for the repo just cloned, you can now go to the newly cloned repo and add the empty-proxy setting.

```
$> git config --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

However, if you want this host or IP excluded from proxy in all cases, use your shells init-file to do the inclusion of your origins permanent for your user.

I would put the following line last in .bashrc

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,<your repo>
```

I hope that makes things clearer!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to clone a new repo, some solutions given in other answers will fail, because git complains that the local folder contains no git repository.

In this case this worked for me

```
git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to Windows / Unix user role, if you can't eliminate the http_proxy from command line, please try this approach -

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

That will print the configurations based present on the files according to hierarchy. Now go to specific file (local .git/config folder file) and update / remove the http_proxy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not one of the answers could help me with this issue. Fortunatelly I could find a website which provided me with the only working solution:

In the root of the project, you can find a hidden .git folder. Inside it, there is a file called "config". Just open it and add these lines:

```
[http]
        proxy =
[https]
        proxy =
```

Immediately after the change I could finally clone, pull and push again.

Credits: https://collectednotes.com/agusluques/git-commands-ignoring-proxy-on-windows

Answer (score -1):

Old question but here is how to configure this globally:

1. Set the proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy.example.com:3128
```

2. Turn off the proxy for specific URLs by setting the their proxy to the empty string (replace *myserver.localdomain* with your server FQDN):

```
git config --global http.https://myserver.localdomain.proxy ''
```

Answer (score -5):

just execute below command on command prompt

```
git config --global http.proxy [Proxy IP]:[Proxy port]
```