# 504 gateway timeout on GitLab HTTP URLs

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab, git-gui, atlassian-sourcetree

I have installed GitLab 6.0 on a linux box and created a number of projects.  I can create a local clone of each project using the SSH URL, but when I try to use the HTTP URL I get a **504 Gateway Timeout within seconds**.

- When I paste the HTTP URL into SourceTree it says "Checking source" for a second or so, then "This is not a valid source path / URL".  When I click on "Details..." it says:

> The requested URL returned error: 504 while accessing http://myserver/group/project.git/info/refs

- Git Gui also attempts to access the http ://myserver/group/project.git/info/refs URL and gets a 504 error.
- When I attempt to open this "info/refs" URL in a browser I get a "**Authentication Required**" popup which ** does not accept** my GitLab username/password nor email/password.
- The Eclise EGit plugin has fields to provide a username & password - if I fill those out then I get a list of branches, but then I get a "Read timed out" on the clone operation (the repo is 2GB).  This approach **does work on smaller projects** on my GitLab server.

As per the instructions, I've used nginx, but it seems to be the source of a number of problems that I'm having.

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`:

```
System information
System:         Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      yes
RVM Version:    1.6.9
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p0
Gem Version:    1.8.11
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:        6.0.0
Revision:       5246d63
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            http://myserver
HTTP Clone URL: http://myserver/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@myserver:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        1.7.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 7):

This usually is a proxy server issue. Just open a terminal and run this command to bypass the proxy for the remote. (assuming your remote server is called "origin"):

```
git config --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

More info here: [Git proxy bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538372/git-proxy-bypass)