# Configure GitLab repository in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to configure Jenkins (running on Windows Server 2008) to connect to a GitLab 6.0 repository (on a linux box).

From my local windows box I can use the SSH URLs to clone the projects on my GitLab server.  I've had [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501296/504-gateway-timeout-on-gitlab-http-urls) using the HTTP URLs, but I did manage to connect using HTTP with authentication using the Eclipse plugin.

- On the Jenkins project config screen I have attempted:

  http://myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git

> Failed to connect to repository :
>
> Command "d:\tools\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h http://myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git HEAD"
>
> returned status code 128:
>
> stdout:  stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 504 while accessing
>
> http://myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

When I try this URL in a browser I get an authentication popup.  If I enter my email & password I can successfully download the list of branches & tags.

- ...Okay, so I should be able to specify the username & password in the URL, right?

  http://username:password@myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git

...nope:

> http://username:password@myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

- The Windows GUIs didn't have any trouble using SSH.
  ...Jenkins doesn't seem to like that much though:

  git@myserver.domain:mygroup/myproject.git

  The error "Please enter Git repository" still remains, and when I attempt to save the config I see the following stack trace:

  ```
  Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from 
  {"value":"2",
   "userRemoteConfigs":     
     {"url":"git@myserver.domain:mygroup/myproject.git",
      "name":"origin","refspec":""
     },
   "branches":{"name":""},
   "includedRegions":"","excludedRegions":"","excludedUsers":"",
   "localBranch":"","relativeTargetDir":"","reference":"",
   "scmName":"",
   "gitConfigName":"","gitConfigEmail":"",
   "pruneBranches":false,"skipTag":false,"clean":false,"remotePoll":false,
   "disableSubmodules":false,"recursiveSubmodules":false,
   "authorOrCommitter":false,"wipeOutWorkspace":false,"ignoreNotifyCommit":false,
   "useShallowClone":false,"":["","0"],
   "gitTool":"Default",
   "browser":{"stapler- class":"hudson.plugins.git.browser.FisheyeGitRepositoryBrowser"}

  Stacktrace:
  javax.servlet.ServletException: 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {...}
  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:725)
  ...
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {...}
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:617)
    ...
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.RepositoryBrowser.normalizeToEndWithSlash(RepositoryBrowser.java:85)
    at hudson.plugins.git.browser.FisheyeGitRepositoryBrowser.<init>(FisheyeGitRepositoryBrowser.java:37)
  ```
- I tried adding the "ssh" protocol:

  ssh://git@myserver.domain:mygroup/myproject.git

Jenkins immediately reacts:

> stderr: ssh: myserver.domain:mygroup: no address associated with name
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Maybe Jenkins doesn't support the scp syntax (with ':') Try ssh://git@myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git

Comment: Thanks VonC - could you please submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501767/configure-gitlab-repository-in-jenkins?noredirect=1#comment27204678_18501767):

Maybe Jenkins doesn't support the scp syntax (with '`:`') Try

```
 ssh://git@myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git
```

As mentioned in "[.ssh config with amazon ec2 and git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309)", using '`:`' usually involves a `~/.ssh/config file`, which resolves the string preceding the ':' into a server, user, port and ssh key.

Jenkins might understand better `git@myserver.domain/mygroup/myproject.git` instead of `git@myserver.domain:mygroup/myproject.git`.