# Local Jenkins (on Windows) Connecting to GitLab

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I have been running into many issues regarding having Jenkins (that is running on my local Windows laptop), and being able to connect to a GitLab repo that is private (I have full access to it) and so I have added the private key to Jenkins (I had originally not realized I did not convert my key from putty to OpenSSH so I have fixed that), I have the deploy key which uses the public key in GitLab, and then I have the .ssh folder in multiple places in my local file system as I have read people saying to put it here and there, they all have the same keys, but I have them in my root C, Git, and Jenkins folders. I am now restarting Jenkins to see if that helps, but I have been able to clone on my local machine the Gitlab repo using Git bash, using "git clone git@URL.git", and it was successful, but when trying to build on Jenkins it, it shows this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@URL.git # timeout=10 
Fetching upstream changes from git@URL.git 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@URL.git +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ 
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes 
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' 
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' 
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have no idea what to do from here, I have been looking through these issues for a couple days now, I assume it might be an issue with keys, but I have also read about issues with some of the paths, so I have tried manually specifying files in Jenkins configuration, and ensured things such as using the Git path with 'cmd,' not sure if anyone else has configured Jenkins on Windows connecting to Gitlab has any experience with these issues, but I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/297500/jenkins-windows-service-with-git-over-ssh

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501767/configure-gitlab-repository-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up getting it to work by using the HTTP URL provided by GitLab versus using the SSH URL, and using that URL, and then I added my login credentials to from GitLab for authentication and that got my Jenkins up and running.