# git how switch proxy settings for different networks

Tags: git, github, proxy

I work at a company and from home too using my laptop running Ubuntu Linux. The code is in a github repo. At company I access the network via a http proxy while at home there is no proxy. How to git push/pull in such cases? How to tell git to use proxy when at company and not to use proxy when at home?

This seems different than [How to temporarily disable git http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523903/how-to-temporarily-disable-git-http-proxy), because in my case, I am accessing remote repo in both cases and not a local repo as in that question/answer.

My situation seems to be different than what is described in this question too [git-proxy-bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538372/git-proxy-bypass/16612442#16612442)

What I want is to access my github repo in two ways:

1. From behind company proxy
2. From my home network without proxy

I have to do this quite frequently.

Comment: Are you not using two different configs in the two different machines?

Comment: It is the same machine, my laptop.

Comment: May you make two scripts to be run manually to add or remove remote origin proxy?

Comment: You can write a script A to set up the company proxy, and a script B to set up no proxy. Then, write a wrapper script to be called when your laptop connects to a wifi (refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript), and this script should programmatically run script A or B.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- use a different account and declare your proxy in your global Git settings.
  Those are stored in `\Path\To\yourAccount\.gitconfig`, which means two different settings depending on your workplace.
- use a script that you launch automatically when you start your OS, which will:

  - detect if a proxy is needed (try accessing a known url: if it fails, you need to set a proxy with authentication)
  - declare the [`HTTP(S)_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309) accordingly.

Comment: my machine is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @sandy that works with Linux as well: your .bashrc can trigger the script whenever you open a shell. Or your .profile can trigger the script whenever you log on.

Comment: but you have said to use a different account, which may be error prone and cumbersome.

Comment: @sandy I said "either" (you can either do A or B): if you don't want to use a separate account, you can create a script which will test internet access and determine, when you open a new session, if proxy needs to be set or not.