# gitlab intellij plugin received HTTP code 400

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab-ci

I use GitLab Projects Plugin in IntelliJ idea to connect to my repository.
when I want to commit my changes I receive

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://server:port/usr/project.git/': Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT
```

how can I handle this error. thank you

Comment: with atom I got same error too

Comment: this is my log from  /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/logs/gitlab_access.log      "-  -" 400 166 "" "-"

Answer (score 0):

Seems the error is from command line git, and I believe you get it on push, not commit. There appears to be some proxy in use that does not work well. Probably you could bypass it by removing git proxy settings. See e.g. [Git proxy bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538372/git-proxy-bypass)